# What is the background video-size limit for optimal performance speed on my website?

Tags: css, html, video

Currently I have a 50% window-height video as a background header on my website. The current size is +-150MB but I'd like to increase it's quality but without making my website laggy or slower.

What would be the max size to maintain optimal peformance?

Comment: Nothing close to 150MB. Cut down the length and compress it properly. Only you can decide what is a satisfactory size for your videos but I'd avoid any sort of background video going over 5MB

Comment: Have you heard of FFmpeg? The options there might help you reach a satisfactory Filesize vs Picture Quality ratio... Keep it 5mb. Test on a large screen (TV) & see if you really need extra HD quality for a website **background**? Think of your end users. Not everyone on mobile can afford to use 150mb of their data on just your background Not everyone's internet will be fast enough.